# MVVM Light Portable Class Library Navigation

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation, mvvm-light

I am making a Windows Phone 8 app using the MVVM architecture and a portable class library. I am currently using MVVM light messages to navigate to a new page. Is there a different approach that I can use instead of messages because I always have to put code in the code behind.

Comment: Depends a bit of your set up... but in most of my cases I trigger a navigation when a change has happend on the page and this change is passed through to the ViewModel with commands. From the ViewModel you can just use the NavigationService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look here https://github.com/cmorgado/MultiPlatform

I've tackled some of cross platform tips&tricks... the example show things as navigation, NFC, GPS from a PCL point of view..